# Is there a different way I can use the items in a list exclude boundaries?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the list `A=[2,32,41,2,4,73,5,9,20]`. If I want to create a list `B` whose elements are the sum of neighboring elements in `A`, boundary values 2 and 20 excluded, here's the code I have:

```
A=[2,32,41,2,4,73,5,9,20]
B = []
for i in range (1,len(A)-1):
    B.append(A[i-1]+A[i+1])
>>> B
>>> [43, 34, 45, 75, 9, 82, 25]
```

I'm just wondering is there a better way I can generate the list `B`? This pattern is what I usually rely on while coding with some problems like that, but I really want to know if there's a better/easier way I can use the elements in a list/array with excluded boundary points. (instead of using `range`, as what I did here)

Many thanks for the help and suggestions!

Comment: I would say this is a really well done method. Great job. I would say, you can implement list comprehension here.

Comment: @ZR- You code has `O(N)` complexity. pretty good, but like @BuddyBod suggested using a list comprehension can boost the performance. I suggest you to work on the PEP8 coding standards instead and also in stackoverflow use upvote for conveying thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [109]: A
Out[109]: [2, 32, 41, 2, 4, 73, 5, 9, 20]

In [110]: [a + b for a,b in zip(A, A[2:])]
Out[110]: [43, 34, 45, 75, 9, 82, 25]
```

Slightly better performance using `zip` and list comp. Using [`%timeit`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) to measure, ops version is `b` my version is `a`:

```
In [114]: %timeit  a(A)
1.06 µs ± 7.63 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [115]: %timeit  b(A)
1.63 µs ± 9.72 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do using with list comprehension:

```
a = [2, 32, 41, 2, 4, 73, 5, 9, 20]
b = [i + j for (i,j) in zip(a[:-2], a[2:])]
b
[43, 34, 45, 75, 9, 82, 25]
```